# Add a subdomain condition to password reset query in Devise with Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've setup Devise (on Rails 3) to use Basecamp-style subdomain authentication. Under this model, a user could be registered twice under different subdomains with the same email address.

For example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  # subdomain attribute stored here
end
```

**User 1** registered on company1.myapp.com with email address bob@acme.com
**User 2** registered on company2.myapp.com with email address bob@acme.com

(Both user account are controlled by the same human, but belong to different subdomains.)

Logging in works fine, but the standard Password Reset only looks up by email address, so you can only ever reset the password for **User 1**. What I'd like to do is take into account the request subdomain, so a password reset from company2.myapp.com/password/new would reset the password for **User 2**.

The Devise looks up the user using a find_first method, which I don't think accepts joins, so I can't include a `:account => {:subodmain => 'comapny2'}` condition.

I can reimplement `send_reset_password_instructions` to manually look up the user record, but it feels hacky and I'll need to do it for `send_confirmation_instructions`, too.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this may be configurable with `devise_for` in the routes file.

From my reading of the source (and I haven't actually tried this), you can add a `reset_password_keys` option. These should include the subdomain. This is passed to `find_or_initialize_with_errors` from `send_reset_password_instructions` in [`lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb#L98). In `find_or_initialize_with_errors` it's [only these keys which are used to find the resource](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb#L130).

You'll probably also want to override `Devise::PasswordsController#new` template to include the user's subdomain when they submit the reset password request.

**UPDATE**: to address the fact that the subdomain is stored on Account and User `belongs_to :account` you can probably use [Rails' `delegate` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate).

Comment: You are correct about the reset_password_keys option, but that will get passed in as a condition on the User model. I have the subdomain stored on the Account model (which the User belongs_to) so passing it through reset_password_keys doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I just re-read my original question and realised my code example was incorrect - I had called the Account model User, which didn't make sense. Fixed now.

Comment: OK, no worries. I updated my answer, hopefully that gets you where you need.

Answer (score 1):

We experienced this same issue.  Mike Mazur's answer worked, but for one difference:
We put `:reset_password_keys => [:email, :subdomain]` in the call to the `devise` method in our Users model.

Answer (score 1):

I recently implement this behaviour in a Rails 4 App.

…/config/initializers/devise.rb

```
(…)
# ==> Configuration for :recoverable
#
# Defines which key will be used when recovering the password for an account
config.reset_password_keys = [:email, :subdomain]
(…)
```

…/app/views/devise/passwords/new.html.erb

```
(…)
<%= f.input :subdomain, required: true %>
(…)
```

…/app/controllers/users/passwords_controller.rb

```
class Users::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController

  def resource_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :subdomain, ...)
  end

  private :resource_params
end
```